# Does Kotlin's launch start a coroutine in the main or a background thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to run a task in the background on Android, and I was wondering whether I need to specify `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` or if a simple `GlobalScope.launch { ... }` is enough. My worry is whether the second form launches the coroutine **in the main or a background/IO thread**?

---

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#use-coroutines-for-main-safety),

> `launch` doesn't take a `Dispatchers.IO` parameter. When you don't pass a `Dispatcher` to launch, any coroutines launched from `viewModelScope` **run in the main thread**.

According to [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#dispatchers-and-threads),

> The default dispatcher that is used when coroutines are launched in GlobalScope is represented by Dispatchers.Default and **uses a shared background pool of threads**, so `launch(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }` uses the same dispatcher as `GlobalScope.launch { ... }`.

I know coroutines were experimental until recently, and Android-Kotlin vs pure-Kotlin development are different, but these statements seem contradictory to me.

Comment: actually viewModelScope different GlobalScope, it means maybe viewModelScope.launch can run in different dispatcher with GlobalScope.launch

Comment: [GlobalScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) has [EmptyCoroutineContext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-empty-coroutine-context/) which implies Dispatchers.Default will be used when directly launching within it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GlobalScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) has [EmptyCoroutineContext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-empty-coroutine-context/) which implies Dispatchers.Default will be used when directly launching within it.

Example demonstrating the behavior: https://pl.kotl.in/cLy3UfuZO

> My worry is whether the second form launches the coroutine in the main or a background/IO thread?

It'll launch it into CommonPool under Dispatchers.Default which shares max thread same as number of cores in your CPU, for instance if your CPU has 6 cores then there will be a max limit of 6 threads. Dispatchers.IO however allows upto borrowing 64 threads from the CommonPool. Dispatchers.Main is single threaded.

---

Story of `viewModelScope` is different, that scope contains `Dispatchers.Main` as its default dispatcher to launch in. You can create a scope like this `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)` so that every launch without specifying dispatcher will launch in the Main similar to the `viewModelScope`.

Comment: Ah, so I just misunderstood the Android example. Thanks!